# Eclipse: How, if possible, can I change the color of the final keyword?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse 3.7.1. In preferences->editor->syntax coloring there is no element for the final keyword under Java, it is only possible to change syntax coloring of the return keyword and "all other keywords". So it seems I am out of luck.

Comment: I'm going to guess that it's not possible to change the highlighting for individual keywords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As illustrated by [bug 193336](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=193336), color preferences are only available for all keywords or for a specific one when explicitly required (like, in this case, "`return`").

You can see actually with the [associated patch](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=71757) for this bug how the preference has been implemented.

Answer (score 0):

The following link provides various collor themes for eclipse: 
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-color-theme

But i believe that FINAL keyword cannot be highlighted.